# How do I see the Trello welcome board again?

Tags: trello

I want to read the welcome board again. How do I get it up again?

Comment: Oops while posting this I realised I had either archived or closed it. I found it under closed items and was able to reactivate it and then take the lists with the info out from archived things.

I like Trello - it might puzzle you but you work out within a few minutes how to do it. The logic of it is sound.

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer that way you can accept your own answer and help future visitors that may be having the same problem. Thanks

Comment: A read-only version of the welcome board is available at https://trello.com/board/welcome-board/4e6a8095efa69909ba007382

Answer (score 3):

Every new user gets a Welcome Board. You have probably closed yours. You can re-open any closed board.

To re-open a closed board:

1. Click on the **Boards** menu (near the upper-right corner of the page)
2. Click on the **View Closed Boards** menu item (near the bottom of the Boards menu)
3. Find the Welcome board and click **re-open**

That's it!